# How to hide an api key on github repo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I have simple **html+css+js** web setup and I would like to host it on github publicly, but I am using a third party api, so how can I hide the api key of same on github repo. Can someone help me out?

Comment: you can use this this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: you can't hide it on github, if it's on github (public repo) then it's public by definition

Comment: Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648652/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-github-page) on a somewhat similar case.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.
If you just want to hide it from git repo, i create another api key file and store my api like this

`export const apikey= '12341234123'`
after that I just add it to the gitignore folder.

If you don't know what the gitignore folder is or how to create it, it is pretty straight forward. Here is a guide:
[How to create a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file)