# gh-pages deployment issue, job fails on deploy. The directory you're trying to deploy ... doesn't exist

Tags: deployment, devops, github-pages, github-actions

gh-pages deployment fails with next error: [My repository failed job](https://github.com/nikonov91-dev/azure-flask-react/runs/1919880719?check_suite_focus=true)

```
Checking configuration and starting deployment… 
Error: The directory you're trying to deploy named /home/runner/work/azure-flask-react/azure-flask-react/dist doesn't exist. Please double check the path and any prerequisite build scripts and try again. ❗
Deployment failed! ❌
```

[image: duplicated directory path in gh-pages job]

I'm trying to deploy *ReactApp at Github and besides deploy Python-Flask backend* hosted at Azure and back-app has its automatically *generated job yml*.

But for front-app I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648652/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-github-page) and manually added second job in yml because I need to provide env.variables.

My backend deployment succeeds but front-app constantly fails because of duplicated path
*/home/runner/work/**azure-flask-react**/**azure-flask-react**/dist*

[Here is my yml](https://github.com/nikonov91-dev/azure-flask-react/blob/main/.github/workflows/main_first-py-app.yml) and [package.json](https://github.com/nikonov91-dev/azure-flask-react/blob/main/front-app/package.json) but there is no any extra mentioning of that directory...

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - first-py-app

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  front-build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm --prefix front-app install
          npm --prefix front-app run-script build
        env:
          REACT_DEV_SERVER_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_DEV_SERVER_URL }},
          REACT_DEV_FRONT_APP_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_DEV_FRONT_APP_URL }}

      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN_KEY }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: dist

  back-build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      - name: Build using AppService-Build
        uses: azure/appservice-build@v2
        with:
          platform: python
          platform-version: '3.8'

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'first-py-app'
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_7edcdecca83a4354a87943f94bb32fca }}
```

```
{
  ...
  "homepage": "https://nikonov91-dev.github.io/azure-flask-react",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
}
```

and my file structure

```
azure-proj
  |-front-app (containing reactjs)
     |-package.json
     |-node_modules
     |-src
  |-app.py (python-flask application which deploys successfully)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the issue message, the problem was not duplicating part of the path; the problem was the missed inner path passed in **FOLDER** in **gh-pages YML settings**

[image]

There was a hint in *BUILD* step

[image]

And one more thing: do not forget to get and add to GH your [personal-access-token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

[image]

Comment: "the problem was the missed inner path passed in FOLDER in gh-pages YML settings" ...but what was the problem with 'front-app/build'?  That still looks right to me. How did you fix given the path that your build step showed?