# cannot access environment secrets variables passing it from GH-pages to ReactApp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, github-pages, github-actions

I'm trying to use environment variables in ReactApp deploying at Github-pages.

The variable is added through ***process.env*** and starts with ***REACT_APP*** as docs prescribe

```
export default class WeatherService {
  constructor() {
    this.API_WEATHER_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL + 'api/weather';
  }
```

and ***.env*** created with ***GitHub Actions yml***

```
jobs:
  front-build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Store variables
        run: |
          cd front-app
          touch .env
          REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }} >> .env

      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd front-app
          npm install
          npm run-script build
      - name: Deploy
          ...
```

but the app gets wrong values from GitHub Secrets.

[image]

see the react-app at GH-pages receives a wrong object, not what i've passed ("username.cloudTech.com/api"):

```
this.API_BLOB_URL = Object({
                NODE_ENV: "production",
                PUBLIC_URL: "/azure-flask-react",
                WDS_SOCKET_HOST: void 0,
                WDS_SOCKET_PATH: void 0,
                WDS_SOCKET_PORT: void 0,
                FAST_REFRESH: !0
            }).REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL + "api/blob/"
```

At the same time when I build locally with ***npm run build***. React successfully replaces the env. variables

[image: environmental variable replaced with react]

As used to the purpose is to use different environment settings as api dev server in

- *development (127.0.0.1:5000)* and
- *production (username.cloudTech.com/api)*.

I've already tried to use ***env-cmd*** and ***dotenv*** lib but it neither worked

---

UPDATE:

If I pass *REACT_APP_ENV='username.cloudTech.com/api'* npm script - it passes this variable successfully:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "REACT_APP_FRONT_APP_URL=nikonov91-dev.github.io/azure-flask-react/ npm run build"
    ...
}
```

And then voila.

[image: environment variable in deployed react app]

---

UPDATE on @OldPro`s answer.
I've quoted my line:

```
run: |
  cd front-app
  touch .env
  echo 'REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}' >> .env
```

but the value is still empty in JS ch:
[image]

---

I've tried also the answer of @peterevans

```
        run: |
          cd front-app
          echo "DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          touch .env
          echo "REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ env.DEV_SERVER_URL }}" >> .env
```

unfortunately the variable is the same

---

UPDATE

*I'm sure my approach is working because if I hardcode the variable in **YML** it works as should and can be easily accessed in my Appv*

```
 - name: Store variables
        run: |
          cd front-app
          touch .env
          echo "REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL='https://first-py-app.azurewebsites.net/'" >> .env
```

and
`this.API_BLOB_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL + 'api/blob/';`
becomes
`this.API_BLOB_URL = "https://first-py-app.azurewebsites.net/api/blob/"`

---

BUT I STILL LOOKING FOR solution how to pass variable from **GH-Secrets**

Comment: Could you paste your source code directly in your post so it's searchable? It's also helpful to visually impaired users that rely on screenreaders.

Comment: @jidicula, sure, check it please, I've replaced important pictures with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out there are two approaches:

- ***Repository Secrets***
  may be set **Settings**->**Secrets**->**New repository secret**
- ***Environment Secrets***
  may be created **Settings**->**Environments**->**New environment**->**Add secret**

  and add to job description next argument: *environment: your-wanted-env* as it is in my code

*Environment Secrets* needs additional argument in *job* description:

```
jobs:
  trying-to-use-environment-secrets:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: test-env #<---The only difference we need to specify what environment to use for environment secrets
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Store variables
        run: |
          echo ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_SECRETS }}
          echo "DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL_FROM_REPOSITORY_SECRETS }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

In your update, you say

> I'm sure my approach is working because if I hardcode the variable in YML it works as should and can be easily accessed in my Appv

I ran my own test. I created a secret named `DEV_SERVER_URL` and set it to `https://first-py-app.azurewebsites.net/`

Then I ran this job:

```yaml
jobs:
  env-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Store variables
      run: |
        mkdir front-app
        cd front-app
        touch .env
        echo 'REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}' >> .env

    - name: Leak variables
      run: |
        cd front-app
        ls -al
        cat .env
        cat .env | hexdump
```

It produced this output, as expected (note the `***` is in the original output, as GitHub censors secrets automatically):

[image: Output of GitHub action run]

(violating the rule about posting text because I want to preserve the formatting). The important thing about this output is the hexdump at the end.

```sh
$ echo 'REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=https://first-py-app.azurewebsites.net/' | hexdump -x
0000000    4552    4341    5f54    5041    5f50    4544    5f56    4553
0000010    5652    5245    555f    4c52    683d    7474    7370    2f3a
0000020    662f    7269    7473    702d    2d79    7061    2e70    7a61
0000030    7275    7765    6265    6973    6574    2e73    656e    2f74
0000040    000a                                                        
0000041
```

It means the secret is being saved in the `.env` file as expected. So I have to conclude that your problem is that the secret `DEV_SERVER_URL` is either empty or not accessible to your action runner. I suggest you run the same job I did and see what results you get.

---

#### Original answer

Although pictures can be nice sometimes, they should be in addition to, not a substitute for, including code as text. People can search and edit text, but not pictures.

According to your picture, your GitHub Action includes a step like this:

```yaml
run: |
  cd front-app
  touch .env
  REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }} >> .env
```

So your first problem is that the last line above only sets the environment variable for that step and does nothing to the `.env` file. What you probably meant or want is

```yaml
run: |
  cd front-app
  touch .env
  echo 'REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}' >> .env
```

That will put the assignment in the `.env` file. Whether that is sufficient for your needs will depend on the rest of your action.

Comment: thanks for you help, but the value is still empty of that variable ```this.API_BLOB_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL```

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov Like I said, it depends on the rest of your build steps. All we have done so far is get `REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=some-secret` into a file named `.env` in the directory `front-app`. Now you need to use that file as part of your build and deploy. My guess is that you are not deploying the `.env` file onto the server where the code is running.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I tested it already (see my last update in the answer) that shows my approach is correct. I suppose there is an issue in GH actions or something is not described in docs fully

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov OK, if the approach is correct, then the data is suspect. See my revised answer.

Comment: it works but only for REPOSITORY SECRETS, but all the time I've tried to access ENVIRONMENT SECRETS. (please check my answer below, may be you have any idea why it is)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the way GitHub Actions recommends to [set environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).

Change your "Store variables" step to look like this:

```yaml
      - name: Store variables
        run: |
          echo "REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL=${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: thanks, I've read the article and tried it, but result is the same, it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else in the `.env` file that you need for your react app? I'm not very familiar with ReactJS project structure, but I'm wondering why you're not using the `env` directive in your workflow and [passing the secret in the environment variable declaration](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow), then accessing the environment variable directly from `npm run build`:

```yaml
jobs:
  front-build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL: ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_URL }}
    steps:
      ...
      # $REACT_APP_DEV_SERVER_URL is now available to any steps in the job
```

Comment: it doesnt work this way because nodejs takes all environmental variables from .env on building. I've already tried